Integral with singularities
Let $n > 1$ and $1 \le k \le (n-2)$ be integers, and set
$$f(x) := (-1)^n k \left(\frac{k u \sin (k \pi  u)}{n-k u}+\frac{(k+1) u \cos \left((k+1) \pi  \sqrt{u}\right)}{(k+1)u-n}+\frac{n}{\pi }\left(\frac{\cos (k \pi  u)}{(n-k u)^2}-\frac{\sin ((k+1) \pi  u)}{(k-n+1)^2}\right)\right)$$
I want to calculate the integral
$$\int_1^n f(u) du$$
Note that $f(x)$ has singularities at $x = \frac {n}{k}$ and  $x = \frac {n}{k+1}$. Here, for example, is a plot of $f$ with $n = 7$ and $k = 2$:

It looks to me as though the integral could be broken into segments and calculated using limits:
$$\int_1^n f(u) du = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_1^{\frac{n}{k+1}-\epsilon} f(u) du + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\frac{n}{k+1}+\epsilon}^{\frac{n}{k}-\epsilon} f(u) du + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\frac{n}{k}-\epsilon}^n f(u) du$$
But I can't make it work. If I aim for a general solution (i.e., a formula for all $n,k$), I either get zero or infinity - and I'm not entirely convinced by either answer, especially when expressed as a sum of limits.
I confess that I am using Mathematica to do the heavy lifting. However, I honestly don't think this is a coding issue; I can obtain numerical results, I just can't get a general formula without imposing conditions that I know don't apply (such as $k$ being imaginary).
I suspect I am missing something fairly fundamental about $f$ - or about singularities in general. But what? More importantly, is it possible to calculate the integral in the general case? If so, how?

The singularity at $u = \frac{n}{k + 1}$ only has order $1$ (you can see from the plot that the singularity at the smaller $u$-value has odd order). In any case, the singularities are nonintegrable, so the integral is not defined. I suspect there is a typo somewhere, as the last term isn't even defined when $k = n - 1$.

Thanks @Travis. I have made edits to adjust for your comments. Although you say, "the singularities are non-integrable, so the integral is not defined", I don't see how this applies in the limiting cases I discussed...?

Each of the finite integrals over the given intervals converges for small $\epsilon > 0$, but they diverge as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Strictly speaking to define the improper integral over the middle interval, you should let the limits tend to the endpoints independently, i.e., write something like $\int_{\frac{n}{k+1} + \delta}^{\frac{n}{k} - \epsilon} \cdots dx$. In this case, though, the integral diverges regardless, I think: The singularities are the endpoints are nonintegrable and have different orders and so even when using a single parameter $\epsilon$ the singular parts don't cancel.

At any rate, one can write down a closed-form antiderivative of the integrand in terms of the sine integral and cosine integral functions, but it's a mess.

OK, thanks @Travis. That all makes sense. I you want to write that out as an answer, I'll accept it. Else, I'll just consider the case closed!

Both singularities of the integrand $f$ on the interval $[1, n]$ of integration are nonintegrable, so the integral is not defined.

There is a simple pole at $u = \frac{n}{k + 1}$: Its Laurent series expansion is
$$f(u) \sim \frac{(-1)^n k n \cos \pi \sqrt{n (k + 1)}}{k + 1} \left(u - \frac{n}{k + 1}\right)^{-1} + R_1(u);$$
there is a double pole at $u = \frac{n}{k}$:
$$f(u) \sim \frac{n}{\pi k} \left(u - \frac{n}{k}\right)^{-2} + R_2(u).$$
The remainders $R_1(u), R_2(u)$ are both in $O(1)$.

The presence of the double pole means that the integral is not even convergent in a principal value sense.
Finally, the integral has a closed-form antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions and the sine and cosine integral functions, but it is long and not illuminating, so I will not reproduce it here.

Thank you @Travis. Much appreciated
